# Xcode working on simulators and not on mobile; getting error code 1

Tags: ios, xcode

Sorry, I am very new to xcode

What does this mean?

> CopySwiftLibs
>   /Users/test1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ARPetSnakes-avdbyvfyluotmrhiifepeuelspqd/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ARPetSnakes.app
>   (in target: ARPetSnakes)
>       cd /Users/test1/Downloads/ARPetSnakes
>       export CODESIGN_ALLOCATE=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
>       export DEVELOPER_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
>       export SDKROOT=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.0.sdk
>       builtin-swiftStdLibTool --copy --verbose --sign 48492F2C83EDB9840D6D34B26E8B169BD4C2FDF0 --scan-executable
>   /Users/test1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ARPetSnakes-avdbyvfyluotmrhiifepeuelspqd/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ARPetSnakes.app/ARPetSnakes
>   --scan-folder /Users/test1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ARPetSnakes-avdbyvfyluotmrhiifepeuelspqd/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ARPetSnakes.app/Frameworks
>   --scan-folder /Users/test1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ARPetSnakes-avdbyvfyluotmrhiifepeuelspqd/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ARPetSnakes.app/PlugIns
>   --platform iphoneos --toolchain /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain
>   --destination /Users/test1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ARPetSnakes-avdbyvfyluotmrhiifepeuelspqd/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ARPetSnakes.app/Frameworks
>   --strip-bitcode --resource-destination /Users/test1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ARPetSnakes-avdbyvfyluotmrhiifepeuelspqd/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ARPetSnakes.app
>   --resource-library libswiftRemoteMirror.dylib --strip-bitcode-tool /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/bitcode_strip
>   --emit-dependency-info /Users/test1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ARPetSnakes-avdbyvfyluotmrhiifepeuelspqd/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ARPetSnakes.build/Debug-iphoneos/ARPetSnakes.build/SwiftStdLibToolInputDependencies.dep
>
> Requested Swift ABI version based on scanned binaries: 6
>   libswiftSpriteKit.dylib is up to date at
>   /Users/test1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ARPetSnakes-avdbyvfyluotmrhiifepeuelspqd/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ARPetSnakes.app/Frameworks/libswiftSpriteKit.dylib
>   libswiftUIKit.dylib is up to date at
>   /Users/test1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ARPetSnakes-avdbyvfyluotmrhiifepeuelspqd/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ARPetSnakes.app/Frameworks/libswiftUIKit.dylib
>   libswiftCoreImage.dylib is up to date at
>   /Users/test1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ARPetSnakes-avdbyvfyluotmrhiifepeuelspqd/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ARPetSnakes.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreImage.dylib
>   libswiftModelIO.dylib is up to date at
>   /Users/test1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ARPetSnakes-avdbyvfyluotmrhiifepeuelspqd/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ARPetSnakes.app/Frameworks/libswiftModelIO.dylib
>   libswiftCoreFoundation.dylib is up to date at
>   /Users/test1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ARPetSnakes-avdbyvfyluotmrhiifepeuelspqd/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ARPetSnakes.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreFoundation.dylib
>   libswiftMetal.dylib is up to date at
>   /Users/test1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ARPetSnakes-avdbyvfyluotmrhiifepeuelspqd/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ARPetSnakes.app/Frameworks/libswiftMetal.dylib
>   libswiftGLKit.dylib is up to date at
>   /Users/test1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ARPetSnakes-avdbyvfyluotmrhiifepeuelspqd/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ARPetSnakes.app/Frameworks/libswiftGLKit.dylib
>   libswiftDarwin.dylib is up to date at
>   /Users/test1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ARPetSnakes-avdbyvfyluotmrhiifepeuelspqd/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ARPetSnakes.app/Frameworks/libswiftDarwin.dylib
>   libswiftAVFoundation.dylib is up to date at
>   /Users/test1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ARPetSnakes-avdbyvfyluotmrhiifepeuelspqd/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ARPetSnakes.app/Frameworks/libswiftAVFoundation.dylib
>   libswiftCoreAudio.dylib is up to date at
>   /Users/test1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ARPetSnakes-avdbyvfyluotmrhiifepeuelspqd/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ARPetSnakes.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreAudio.dylib
>   libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib is up to date at
>   /Users/test1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ARPetSnakes-avdbyvfyluotmrhiifepeuelspqd/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ARPetSnakes.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib
>   libswiftQuartzCore.dylib is up to date at
>   /Users/test1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ARPetSnakes-avdbyvfyluotmrhiifepeuelspqd/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ARPetSnakes.app/Frameworks/libswiftQuartzCore.dylib
>   libswiftObjectiveC.dylib is up to date at
>   /Users/test1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ARPetSnakes-avdbyvfyluotmrhiifepeuelspqd/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ARPetSnakes.app/Frameworks/libswiftObjectiveC.dylib
>   libswiftDispatch.dylib is up to date at
>   /Users/test1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ARPetSnakes-avdbyvfyluotmrhiifepeuelspqd/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ARPetSnakes.app/Frameworks/libswiftDispatch.dylib
>   libswiftFoundation.dylib is up to date at
>   /Users/test1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ARPetSnakes-avdbyvfyluotmrhiifepeuelspqd/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ARPetSnakes.app/Frameworks/libswiftFoundation.dylib
>   libswiftSceneKit.dylib is up to date at
>   /Users/test1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ARPetSnakes-avdbyvfyluotmrhiifepeuelspqd/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ARPetSnakes.app/Frameworks/libswiftSceneKit.dylib
>   libswiftCore.dylib is up to date at
>   /Users/test1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ARPetSnakes-avdbyvfyluotmrhiifepeuelspqd/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ARPetSnakes.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib
>   libswiftARKit.dylib is up to date at
>   /Users/test1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ARPetSnakes-avdbyvfyluotmrhiifepeuelspqd/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ARPetSnakes.app/Frameworks/libswiftARKit.dylib
>   libswiftos.dylib is up to date at
>   /Users/test1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ARPetSnakes-avdbyvfyluotmrhiifepeuelspqd/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ARPetSnakes.app/Frameworks/libswiftos.dylib
>   libswiftsimd.dylib is up to date at
>   /Users/test1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ARPetSnakes-avdbyvfyluotmrhiifepeuelspqd/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ARPetSnakes.app/Frameworks/libswiftsimd.dylib
>   libswiftCoreMedia.dylib is up to date at
>   /Users/test1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ARPetSnakes-avdbyvfyluotmrhiifepeuelspqd/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ARPetSnakes.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreMedia.dylib
>   libswiftRemoteMirror.dylib is up to date at
>   /Users/test1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ARPetSnakes-avdbyvfyluotmrhiifepeuelspqd/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ARPetSnakes.app/libswiftRemoteMirror.dylib
>   Probing signature of
>   /Users/test1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ARPetSnakes-avdbyvfyluotmrhiifepeuelspqd/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ARPetSnakes.app/Frameworks/libswiftSpriteKit.dylib
>   /usr/bin/codesign -r- --display
>   /Users/test1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ARPetSnakes-avdbyvfyluotmrhiifepeuelspqd/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ARPetSnakes.app/Frameworks/libswiftSpriteKit.dylib
>   /Users/test1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ARPetSnakes-avdbyvfyluotmrhiifepeuelspqd/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ARPetSnakes.app/Frameworks/libswiftSpriteKit.dylib:
>   code object is not signed at all
>
> Codesigning
>   /Users/test1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ARPetSnakes-avdbyvfyluotmrhiifepeuelspqd/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ARPetSnakes.app/Frameworks/libswiftSpriteKit.dylib
>   /usr/bin/codesign --force --sign
>   48492F2C83EDB9840D6D34B26E8B169BD4C2FDF0 --verbose
>   /Users/test1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ARPetSnakes-avdbyvfyluotmrhiifepeuelspqd/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ARPetSnakes.app/Frameworks/libswiftSpriteKit.dylib
>   /Users/test1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ARPetSnakes-avdbyvfyluotmrhiifepeuelspqd/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ARPetSnakes.app/Frameworks/libswiftSpriteKit.dylib:
>   errSecInternalComponent
>
> error: Failed with exit code 1

Am i right that the errer is due to a code signature?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try to clean?

Comment: @Azat yes I did